# Increase a ProgressBar with Timer in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a timer with an interval of 1 minute and I would like to increase a progress bar in parallel with it. I'm using Winforms and C#. How can I do this ?

Help me please

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use the `Timer` control with a progress bar. First, create a new `Timer` and a `ProgressBar`. then, start the time when the form is loaded, using this function:

```
timer1.Enabled = true; // Enable the timer.
timer1.Start();//Strart it
timer1.Interval = 1000; // The time per tick.
```

Then, create an event for the tick, as shown:

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

Create the event's function:

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

After this, add code to the tick function that adds value to the progress bar, similar to this:

```
progressBar1.Value++;
```

Don't forget to set a maximum value for the progress bar, which you can do by adding this code to the `form_load` function:

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 10; // 10 is an arbitrary maximum value for the progress bar.
```

Also, don't forget to check the maximum value so your timer will stop. You can stop the timer with this code:

```
timer1.Stop();
```

Full Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBar1.Value != 10)
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer. System.Timers.Timer not recognized timer1.Tick. Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Will this work when the tick size and the maximum size of the progressbar aren't values like 1000 and 10?