# Make increments finish at same time

Tags: c#, increment

I have an array of 5 numbers sorted descending : { 289, 151, 69, 27, 6 } :

```
int[] sortedArray = new int[] { 289, 151, 69, 27, 6 };
```

And 5 progressbars on the form.
Each progressbar's Max value = sortedArray[x]

So for example :

```
progressBar0.MaxValue = 289; //First element of array

progressBar1.MaxValue = 151; //2nd

progressBar3.MaxValue = 69; // etc...
```

What I would like to achieve is to **make all the progressbars increment until their respective MaxValue**, but make them **finish at the same time**.

I started by making a new thread for each element of array. But I can't find the algorithm to make them finish together..

```
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var item in sortedArray)
        {
            new Thread(async () =>
            {
              ProgressBar p = Controls.Find("progressbar" + count.ToString(), true)[0] as ProgressBar;
              //how to find the number to increment so they all finish at the same time ? p.Increment(i);
            }).Start();
            cout +=1;
        }
```

I thought of implementing something with a TimeSpan. So for example :

all the progressbars need to be at their MaxValue within 5 seconds..

How can I do do that ?

Comment: You could calulate the current value based on the % amount of time till the 5 seconds are reached and set the value.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Actually using your % calculation idea, he wouldn't need a 5 second limit, if you break every value down into a scale of 100, the same number of increments would make all of them get to 100 (values can be rounded up to account for decimals).

Comment: Why you need to use threads? Use a `Timer` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259511/increase-a-progressbar-with-timer-in-winforms). You just need to calculate the `Interval` property according to the max-value then. For example: `timer.Interval = 5000 / 289`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Great idea!

Comment: Why do each PB have a different `MaxValue`? If they are all the same width in pixels then the UI is scaling the `MaxValue` for you anyway.

Comment: You also can't update a UI element from a non-UI thread. You'll need to invoke the call back to the UI thread so it makes multiple threads a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you are trying to increment them over a period of time what you need to do is work out a factor between 0 and 1 indicating how close you are to completion (based on how much time has elapsed since you started)

Somewhere record the start time. `var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;`

Then in your update code do this

```
var elapsedTime = DateTime.UtcNow - startTime; //How long as elapsed
int progress = elapsedTime.TotalSeconds / 5.0; //Small number / a large number is always 0..1
if (progress > 1) 
  progress = 1;
```

Then the progress bars show their progress based on a scale of 0..MaxValue rather than 0..1, so you just multiply the current progress factor by progressBar.MaxValue

```
someProgressBar.Value = (int)Math.Ceiling(someProgressBar.MaxValue * progress);
```

This is exactly the same as working out percents (per one hundred), you simply multiply the 0..1 factor by 100. That's how you work out a percentage by the way (smallNumber / bigNumber) * 100.

PS: If you do as I suggest and use absolute times then your progress bars will always finish at exactly the correct time. The problem with adding small increments in a loop (for example in a timer) is that if the app is busy/laggy then your timers will complete too late.

Comment: Great this was what I was looking for !! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a case of incrementing them proportionally.

So lets say, for arguments sake, they are all going to increment 5 times. Simply divide each max value by 5 and on each step increment by that amount.

```
int[] sortedArray = new int[] { 289, 151, 69, 27, 6 };
var incrementCount = 5.0;
int incrementAmount = sortedArray.Select(x => Math.Ceil((float)x/incrementCount )).ToArray();
```

You now have an array with the appropriate increment step for each progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some place to write the code to increment the value of the progress bars.

A **timer** is a good choice for this, with `Thread` you cannot have a way to *periodically* update the progress bars.

Now let's create a timer which ticks every second, and we update the progress bars when the timer ticks. We choose `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` so the Tick event handler is run on the UI thread.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
myTimer.Interval = 1000;
myTimer.Tick += (sender, e) => UpdateProgressBars();
myTimer.Start();
```

The next step would be calculating the Value for each progress bar.

For the 1st ProgressBar, at the first tick, the value would be 289/5; at the second tick, it would be (289/5 * 2).

So the UpdateProgressBars method would look like this

```
int counter = 0; //the counter for tick event
private void UpdateProgressBars(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    progressbar1.Value = sortedArray[0] * counter / 5; 
    progressbar2.Value = sortedArray[1] * counter / 5;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only considering one value here, but the solution can easily extended to multiple values.

Inputs:

- Max value: `V_max`
- Timespan where at the end the progress value should equal `V_max`: `timespan`

Progress value:

- `V_progress`

Helpers:

- A `StopWatch` to keep track of elapsed time: `stopwatch`
- A `System.Timers.Timer` to execute regular updates every 10ms: `timer`

When the elapsed time of the stopwatch reached the input timespan, stop updates and set `V_progress` to `V_max`. Otherwise compute `V_progress` as a fraction of `V_max` depending on elapsed time.

```
var V_max = 254;
var V_progress = 0.0;
var timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0);
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
    var elapsedMs = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    var percentage = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / timespan.TotalMilliseconds;
    if (percentage >= 1.0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        percentage = 1.0;
    }
    // probably dispatch this assignment to the UI thread for the actual code
    V_progress = percentage * V_max;
    // test output
    Console.WriteLine(V_progress);
};


stopwatch.Start();
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy on yourself - use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms" (assuming this is Windows Forms)). Then you can do this:

```
ProgressBar[] progressBars = new ProgressBar[] { /* pbs here */ };
int[] sortedArray = new int[] { 289, 151, 69, 27, 6 };

var updates = 100;
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0 / updates))
    .Take(updates)
    .Select(n => sortedArray.Select(x => x * ((int)n + 1) / updates).ToArray())
    .ObserveOn(this)
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray.Length; i++)
        {
            progressBars[i].Value = x[i];
        }
    });
```

I've tested this code and it works just fine, as far as I can tell.